# How to add tooltip to extended form class at runtime?

Tags: c#

I'm stuck in this. I need to add the ToolTip to my own class that extends Form. And I need to do it in code on dynamic Controls aswell.

What I have now is like this:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    private ToolTip _toolTip;

    public MyForm()
        : base()
    {
        setup();
    }

    public MyForm(string Name) 
        : base()
    {
        setup();

        if (Name != null)
        {
            this.myName = Name;
            this.Load += new EventHandler(_Load);
            this.Resize +=new EventHandler(_Resize);
            addMovable(); //This adds the mouse listeners aswell.
        }
    }

    private void setup()
    {
        ...
        this._toolTip = new ToolTip();
    }

    public void SetToolTip(Control control, string caption)
    {
        this._toolTip.SetToolTip(control, caption);
    }

...
```

}

And I call it from something like this.

```
 public void Edit(XmlNode aNode)
{
    XmlNodeList myNodes = aNode.ChildNodes;
    MyForm myForm = new MyForm("EditRollset");
    Button aButton;
    ...
A loop for myNodes..
  {...
    aButton = new Button();
    aButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(btn_Click);
    myForm.SetToolTip(aButton,"FooXMLText");
    myForm.Controls.Add(aButton);
  }
  ...
   myForm.Show();
```

I get no errors or anything, it just do not work..
Please help me.

Comment: The code you have **should work.** What are the settings for the properties like `Active`, `ShowAlways`, and `InitialDelay` for the `_toolTip` object?

Comment: Are you setting the button's location?  If not, you are just putting one on top of the other.  Consider using a FlowLayoutPanel to contain those buttons, then you don't have to worry about the location.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. Do not know what was the problem but after installing the SP1 it works like a charm..